# Excel VBA - breaking a block of text into usable parts

Tags: excel, vba

First time I've run into an excel problem that I havent been able to solve with internet search :(

From our job database system, Im able to export a string of text similar to the below format.  It is basically a stack of changes to a job status.  I want to break this down such that I can record how long each step is taking.  So Id need to break apart the status and the date when that status was changed.

I've bolded every second status change to make it "easier" to read.

Anyone have any ideas?

**Processing  (21/5/2018 11:54:30 AM - Joe Blogs) Processing**
Vietnam Fix  (21/5/2018 8:47:33 AM - Joe Blogs) Vietnam Fix
**Processing  (16/5/2018 8:20:53 AM - Joe Blogs) Processing**
Vietnam Fix  (15/5/2018 12:07:23 PM - Joe Blogs) Vietnam Fix
**Processing  (14/5/2018 11:30:45 AM - Joe Blogs) Processing**
Str. Suff. Letter Printed (10/5/2018 8:46:54 AM - jane.doe.jnr)
**Vietnam Drafting  (9/5/2018 2:49:33 PM - Joe Blogs) Processing**
Processing  (9/5/2018 11:15:18 AM - Joe Blogs) Processing
**Str. Suff. Letter Printed (7/5/2018 2:55:43 PM - jane.doe.jnr)**
Vietnam Layout  (7/5/2018 3:06:32 PM - Joe Blogs) Vietnam Layout
**Str. Suff. Letter Printed (7/5/2018 11:22:18 AM - Joe Blogs)**
Confirmation Emailed   (7/5/18 - Joe Blogs)
**Processing  (7/5/2018 11:21:10 AM - Joe Blogs) Processing**
New (7/5/2018 11:20:52 AM - Joe Blogs)

Comment: SO ain't write-code-for-me site. Can give you a hint to start: user `aLines = Split(ExportedText,"Processing (")` and process aLines array.

Answer (score 0):

Text to columns and Paste Transpose.

You could record these steps to make a vba script or write it yourself:

1. Select the cell with the data
2. Click on Text to Columns
3. Select 'Delimited'
4. Click on Next
5. Tick 'Other' and input an close bracket in the text box **)**
6. Click Finish
7. Highlight the row and copy
8. Select another cell and do a Transpose Paste
9. Select the column with the transposed data
10. Click on Text to Columns
11. Select 'Delimited'
12. Click on Next
13. Tick 'Other' and input an Open bracket in the text box **(**
14. Click Finish
15. Select the newly created column which has the date and time infomation
16. Click on Text to Columns
17. Select 'Delimited'
18. Click on Next
19. Tick 'Other' and input an hyphen in the text box **-**
20. Click Finish

You will now have three columns containing Job, Date/Time and name.

Added for your convenience is the VBA code for the above, I have edited the recorded script to remove all cell selects.

For the script to work, your data needs to be in cell A1 and this row is deleted within in the process:

```
Sub SplitData()

Range("A1").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :=")", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, _
    1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12 _
    , 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Rows("1:1").Copy
Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True

Rows("1:1").Delete Shift:=xlUp

Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :="(", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Columns("B:B").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```